# iOS Safari javascript recursion not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-safari

I've written the following code but I found the `click.intro-mask` event is not correctly registered in iOS Safari. I doubt that it is because of the recursion in `setTimeout` function in the second line from the bottom, but I am not sure. Anyone can help me with this? Why is the click event not working?

```
 function init(cbs) {
    _cbs = cbs;
    var mask = $('<div class="intro-mask"></div>');
    $(document.body).append(mask);
    showIntro();
 }


 function showIntro() {
    console.log('showIntro');
    $(document.body).off('click.intro-mask');
    if (_stage == 6) {
        goFavorstockPage();
    } else {
        var id = 'intro-stage-' + _stage;
        if (_stage) {
            console.log('if _stage:', _stage, '_cbs[_stage]()');
            _cbs[_stage]();
        }
        $('.intro-mask').html('');
        $('.intro-mask').append(introImgTpl({
            imgId: id,
            imgUrl: '/wx/img/' + id + '.png'
        }));
        $('.' + id).load(function() {
          $('.' + id).css({
            "opacity": 1
          });
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
            _stage += 1;
            console.log('in set time out')
            $(document.body).on('click.intro-mask', '.intro-mask', showIntro);
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no recursion in your code?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the second line from the bottom is a recursion, where a click event is registered.

Comment: Do you run this function outside of the click handler, or otherwise attach the click handler to `document.body`, outside of the function?

Comment: Yes, the function is working. It is working on chrome and android browsers but not on safari. I saw the safari devtools there is no click.intro-mask event registered so the `showIntro` function is not invoked when the element is clicked.

Comment: That has to be something in the context of when you attach the event the first time, i.e. outside of `showIntro`.

Comment: just an init function that receives the callbacks from the parent component and builds a element to listen to this click event.